# Pandas List Similarity between Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 456, 789],
                   'list_left': [['dog', 'cat'],['dog', 'mouse'], ['dog', 'elephant']],
                   'list_right': [['cat', 'mouse', 'giraffe'], ['mouse', 'dog'], ['giraffe', 'gorilla']]})
```

I want to find the similarity between the list of strings. This should disregard order or length (i.e. `['dog', 'mouse']` and `['mouse', 'dog']` should result in 100% similarity). Here is my attempt (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-percentage-similarity-of-lists/):

```
df['result'] = len(set(df['list_left']) & set(df2['list_right'][1])) / float(len(set(df['list_left']) | set(df['list_right']))) * 100
```

This results in this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-3b1e1ee16eed> in <module>()
----> 1 df['new'] = len(set(df['list_left']) & set(df2['list_right'][1])) / float(len(set(df['list_left']) | set(df['list_right']))) * 100

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What's a good way to compare to columns of lists within a pandas df? And does the similarity between lists make logical sense for different length lists of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **solution** is to use `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x['list_left']) & set(x['list_right'])) / float(len(set(x['list_left']) | set(x['list_right']))) * 100,1)
```

**Output**:

```
0     25.0
1    100.0
2      0.0
dtype: float64
```

**Explanation of the equation**:

In the equation first you check the common elements:

`df.apply(lambda x: len(set(x['list_left']) & set(x['list_right'])), 1)`

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    0
dtype: int64
```

Next, you check distinct elements of the lists and multiply it by :

```
df.apply(lambda x: float(len(set(x['list_left']) | set(x['list_right']))), 1)
```

Output:

```
0    4
1    2
2    4
dtype: float64
```

The similarity is defined by **(common elements / distinct elements)*100.** So for first row it is `1/4*100 = 0.25`.

Comment: Why is the top row 25% similarity? Shouldn't it be 33% since one item from `list_left` matches one of the three items in `list_right`?

Comment: Notice the lists in question has different sizes.

Comment: Can you please explain why that percentage is 25, though?

Answer (score 1):

Here solution without using `apply`

```
s = df.list_left + df.list_right
s1 = s.map(set)
(s.str.len() - s1.str.len()) / s1.str.len() * 100

Out[132]:
0     25.0
1    100.0
2      0.0
dtype: float64
```